# Cant see Magnolia CMS Page dialog

Tags: magnolia

I am following the Magnolia CMS documentation - 
Creating Page Template. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+a+page+template

How can I see the properties listed on one-pager-module/dialogs/pages/main.yaml ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How can I see the properties listed on one-pager-module/**dialogs**/pages/main.yaml ?

Those are dialog fields. For list of possible types of dialog fields see https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/List+of+fields

If what you want to see are actual properties with values in a page created by that dialog, log into AdminCentral, go to Tools menu and open JCR Browser in there, select "website" workspace and in the displayed tree of pages expand one you have created. It will list all the properties with their values.

HTH,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for all possible options of main.yaml, therefore since its a template definition, one can find the relevant information from: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Template+definition

Cheers,